# How to use HttpClient libraries to download a file from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am attempting to integrate Google Picker on a page. The user uses the picker to sign in into his google account and picks a file. I am trying to use Apache HttpClient libraries to download this file.

Here are the implementation details :

I used Client Side Auth on Javascript as highlighted on this [Google Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). Once I got the 'fileId' of the file, I performed an authenticated [GET](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) using Google Drive API to retrieve the file metadata - name, user, dates, downloadUrl, exportLinks etc. You can use the above link to test the end point and see the responses if you have a fileId.

```js
   function postDownload (resp) {
        var link;
        var data = $.parseJSON (resp);
        console.log (data.webContentLink);
        if (data.mimeType == "application/pdf"){
            link = data.downloadUrl;
        } else {
            link = (data.exportLinks)['application/pdf'];
        }
        //I wish to use the below link to download the file on server side
        //using HttpClient libraries.
        console.log ("Download Link - " +link);
    }

    //Call back after a file is selected on the picker
    function pickerCallback(data) {
        if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var id = data.docs[0].id;
            var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
            console.log (id);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + id);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                postDownload(xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                checkAuth();
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
```

Download Code:

```java
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.http.Header;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    public class DownloadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String link = "https://docs.google.com/uc? id=0ByJwoNOQMrO_S3hlWGRfa2JwVWM&export=download";

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(link);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

If I use the link on the browser or the POSTMAN Chrome Extension, I am able to download the file correctly. The REST clients reports the incoming data correctly as 'application/pdf'.

However, when I use the above Snippet to perform a HttpGet on the URL, the incoming data has a content type of 'text/html' . No clue about this behavior. I don't think the final URL needs to be treated any differently to download the file.

Has anybody faced this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding an authentication header. I guess the auth token is stored in the user's session on the browser and hence I was able to download the file by hitting the URL. For a standalone Java program, we may have to pass the authentication token too.

The below code worked.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class DownloadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String link = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1vE4GVvVVipwMjKsc1q9p75LYWrRy8DZz0APjVFiHL9A";

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(link);
        // get.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        get.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 1vE4GVvVVipwMjKsc1q9p75LYWrRy8DZz0APjVFiHL9A");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to download HttpClient libraries to download a file from Google Drive in Objective c. If any Idea plz reply.